# Is it possible to select option in dropdown list without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

Is it possible to select an item from dropdown list without using jQuery and use AngularJS instead?

I have already implemented it using jQuery but I just wonder if it is possible in AngularJS.

Here's how I did it in jQuery.

```
var dropdownlist = $("select").data("kendoDropDownList");
dropdownlist.select(function(dataItem) {
     return dataItem.name === $scope.person.name;
});
dropdownlist.toggle();
```

Comment: sorry, do you want to have access to the selected item in the drop down list?

Comment: I want to select an item without using $("select").data("kendoDropDownList");

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `ng-Change` in your select option

Sample code is

### Html code

```
<div class="col-sm-6 form-group">               
            <select class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="selectedperson" 
             required **ng-change="selectingPersion(this)"** ng-options="i.person for i in persons">
            </select>

        </div>
```

### Js code

```
$scope.selectingPersion=function(slectedValue)
    {
     var value=slectedValue.person;// See quick watch for what's the value is returnd here
    }
```

This is a key only, You can checkout from my code

else see your result from ng-model value

please checkout `$scope.selectedperson.person`  value